# ARM template error A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Hope somebody can help to resolve the error. Please the link below for the template

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15NYD-4Ghh3-DQV46ydfXgFg_VC0hdTSh

Thanks

> At line:1 char:1
>   + new-azResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ServerResourceGroup ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
>
> new-azResourceGroupDeployment : 13:33:59 - Error:
>   Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed:
>   'The template resource 'diukwestdbuk1/storageAccounts' for type
>   'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' at line '0' and column '0' has
>   incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical
>   number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must
>   have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.
>
> At line:1 char:1
>   + new-azResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ServerResourceGroup ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
>
> new-azResourceGroupDeployment : 13:33:59 - Error:
>   Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed:
>   'The template resource 'diagnosticst1/storageAccounts' for type
>   'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' at line '0' and column '0' has
>   incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical
>   number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must
>   have segment length one greater than its resource name. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this bit is wrong:

```
concat( variables('vardiagstorageName'),copyIndex(1),'/storageAccounts')
```

what the error is trying to suggest you: `/` is used to delimit resource types, so if you use something like `xxx/yyy` when you declare the resource name it implies you are looking to create\update subresource called `yyy` under resource called `xxx`. you need to remove the `/` from your name declation, because in this case you are just creating the storage account.

Comment: Thanks for your help